# Appending empty array for plotting from rows in a csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, matplotlib, append

I have just started using python, so excuse me, if I come off as stupid. However, I was playing around with plotting two different arrays, when I ran into this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    name = row[0] File
>
> "C:/Users/me_irl/PycharmProjects/untitled/lo", line 10, in
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Now, I have scoured the web looking for a solution but after trying pandas, genfromtxt() and other modules unbeknownst to me, I haven't found a resolution.

Here's my code, albeit incomplete, for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import scipy
player_name = []
player_picks = []
with open('C:\exercise.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')
    for row in readCSV:
        name = row[0]
        picks = row[1]

        player_name.append(name)
        player_picks.append(picks)

print(player_name)
```

Here's the part of the csv:

> Salah,94%
>
> Morata,66%
>
> Elliot,64%
>
> Kane,58%
>
> Hazard,52%
>
> de Gea,50%

What should I do? Can someone present me with an easy workaround which doesn't entail using things I haven't learned?

Edit: Figured it out. It had some problems accessing the csv. And no, there weren't any blank lines. Now, trying to plot player_names vs player_picks. Thank you all, who responded. Learnt a lot.

Comment: If your csv file is exactly as you pasted, you need to account for empty lines in your file.

Comment: there are probably blank lines in your csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accounting for the empty lines present in your file.  Add in a check to see if the line has content:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import scipy
player_name = []
player_picks = []
with open('C:\exercise.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if len(row) >= 2:
            name = row[0]
            picks = row[1]

            player_name.append(name)
            player_picks.append(picks)

print(player_name)
```

Comment: `if row` might not be sufficient. You may have to do `len(row) >= 2`

Comment: also don't use full paths with backslashes without the raw prefix.

Comment: Fixed. The access to the CSV was the problem.

Comment: @PrajwalKharel If this answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the statements

```
name = row[0]
picks = row[1]
```

In those lines you try to access items 0 and 1 of the CSV row. If it doesn't have at least 2 items, the error `IndexError: list index out of range` will be prompted.

Comment: This is actually closest to what I was struggling with. Since, the access to the csv was stopped. There was no file to access from, thus explaining the lack of rows.